# Complex bool queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

How to build a query for this kind of match ?

```
(name="Adam" OR name="Bob) OR (age=21 && email="email@gmail.com")
```

How should I "merge" the expressions in parenthesis with and **OR** operation

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","Adam"))
.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name","Bob"));

BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder2 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("age","21"))
.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("email","email@gmail.com"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(queryBuilder1).should(queryBuilder2)
```

This will act as or between two `QueryBuilders`